# SFTP move file does not trigger event

Tags: sftp, ssh2-sftp

I have set an SFTP server and some triggers that I want to launch when a file is ready.

In case I started before it was finished or in case there was an error with the connection, I write first to a `tmp` folder (using SFTP protocol) and once it is copied I move it to a `new` folder.

I'm tracking all events in one folder and the other with inotify:

```
inotifywait -m --format '%:e %f' new
inotifywait -m --format '%:e %f' tmp
```

The events for writing the file in the tmp folder are:

```
CREATE newFile
OPEN newFile
ATTRIB newFile
MODIFY newFile
MODIFY newFile
MODIFY newFile
```

I've noticed that if I move the file from one folder to the other from bash:

```
mv tmp/newFile new
```

A `MOVE_TO` event is triggered.
In the tmp folder:

```
CLOSE_WRITE:CLOSE newFile
MOVED_FROM newFile
```

In the new folder:

```
MOVED_TO newFile
```

However, if I move the file with the RENAME method through SFTP it does not. These are all the events triggered:

In the tmp folder:

```
CLOSE_WRITE:CLOSE newFile
DELETE newFile
```

In the new folder:

```
CREATE newFile
OPEN newFile
ACCESS newFile
CLOSE_NOWRITE:CLOSE newFile
```

Is this part of the protocol of SFTP? Is it possible to move a file in sftp and actually trigger the MOVED_TO event?

This is the implementation for the sftp client that I'm using:
https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2-streams/blob/55fd9c36b6dca8dbf0588a1d6f450b85c784dc72/lib/sftp.js
I'm using openssh-sftp-server for the server

Comment: It might be useful to run `strace` on the sftp server process while performing one of these rename operations. It would show you what system calls the sftp server is making.

Comment: Try to test moving the file with some other SFTP client like WinSCP. Maybe the implementation is doing the RENAME against the standards as it issuing delete, create etc.

Comment: when i manually make a file, it triggered but when the file is programmatically made it did not trigger